# Using system() call in c++ to echo to a file -- string literal is always used instead of > operator?

Tags: c++, linux, posix

Using posix and c++ I am trying the following:

```
std::string command = "echo 1 > myFile";
system(command);
```

The output when ran is always "1 > myFile" output to the terminal, instead of 1 being written to the file.  Thoughts on if this is possible, or how to fix?  Underlying system is linux and bash.

Comment: You should run your command under `strace` to see which shell is executed by `system` and with what parameters.

Comment: `std::system()` takes a C string, not a `std::string`... You might not be calling the version you think you are if that snippet compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `std::system` says that it "Calls the host environment's command processor".
If that is not happening, consider forcing the issue with something akin to

```
system("/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > myFile'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on linux, you can use [popen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

```cpp
#include<cstdlib>
#include<memory>

const char *cmd = "echo 1 > myFile";
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
```